# Don't understand lines and how to assign genres to objects in this class

Tags: java

This is the class Painting:

```
public class Painting {

    private String genre;

    public Painting() {

    }

    public Painting (String aGenre) {
        genre = aGenre;
    }

    public String getGenre(){
        return genre;
    }
}
```

From this class I was trying to create 4 objects and assign each a genre which I did below.

```
public class PaintingGenre {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Painting [] p = new Painting [4];

        p[0].genre = "Brush";
        p[1].genre = "Crayon";
        p[2].genre = "Pencil";
        p[3].genre = "Watercolour";

    }
}
```

However, genre is private in the java class.. is there a way to assign these genres to the four objects/ paintings without changing the genre from private to public in the java class?
I think I can somehow do that by using these lines in the java class below but I don't know what it means... could you explain these lines for me and tell me if and how I can assign genres to the paintings using these lines?

```
public Painting (String aGenre) {
    genre = aGenre;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: You are not creating any objects..

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question. I've rolled it back, and you should look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to see what you should do when someone answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your `genre` field was public, when you try to assign it in your current code, you would end up with a `NullPointerException` anyway, because just creating an array of objects does not actually create objects inside it. This is where your constructor comes in.

This function:

```
public Painting (String aGenre) {
    genre = aGenre;
}
```

is called a constructor. What it does is create a new object and, in this case, take the `String` called "aGenre" and assign it to the object's `genre` field. You can use this to fill out the array you created with `Painting`s with the correct genres.

```
Painting [] p = new Painting [4];
p[0] = new Painting("Brush");
p[1] = new Painting("Crayon");
p[2] = new Painting("Pencil");
p[3] = new Painting("Watercolour");
```

The other function you asked about:

```
public String getGenre(){
    return genre;
}
```

simply returns the genre assigned to the object you call it on. For example:

```
String str = p[0].getGenre(); // str now has the value "Brush"
str = p[1].getGenre(); // str now has the value "Crayon"
```

Answer (score 2):

Without changing the class, the only way to set the value is via the constructor.  So you'd initialize any given instance with the value:

```
p[0] = new PaintingGenre("Brush");
```

The alternative would be to add a setter to the class:

```
public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}
```

and call that on an object (if the object has already been initialized):

```
p[0].setGenre("Brush");
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you don't directly access a field.

The best thing you can do is to implement `Getter` and `Setter`, like this:

```
public Painting (String aGenre) {
    genre = aGenre;
}
public String getGenre(){
    return genre;
}
```

With this code, you set the genre at initialization of the object.

But you'd have to edit your assignment:

```
Painting [] p = new Painting [4];

p[0] = new Painting("Brush");

p[1] = new Painting("Crayon");

p[2] = new Painting("Pencil");

p[3] = new Painting("Watercolour");
```